# If a server is locked - is it posible to send keys to sub client window?

Tags: c#, winapi, setfocus

My program, finds any subwindows, the case if an 3-part app shows an Error box, then i want to close it.. and it works fine, when the server not is locked.

Code:

```
[DllImport("user32", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private extern static bool PostMessage(IntPtr hwnd, uint msg, IntPtr WParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private extern static bool BringWindowToTop(IntPtr hwnd);

public static bool FocusWindowAndSendEnter(IntPtr hWnd)
{
    try
    { // hWnd = pointer to subwindow, like messagebox.

        uint WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;

       //Set focus
      var res1 =  BringWindowToTop(hWnd);

        //Send enter_Key 
      var res2 = PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, (IntPtr)Keys.Enter, IntPtr.Zero);

      return (res1 == res2 == true);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.LogException(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Can this be done if the server is locked, but running?

Comment: (its not working if its looked) - yes i have tried it.

Comment: `res1 == res2 == true`? Really? Why not `res1 == res2 == true == true`?

Comment: I could have Use return (res1 && res2) - its more simple to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a computer is locked, you are very limited in what you can do - for security purposes.  I doubt there is a way around this unless you either stop the computer being locked, or stop the message box from showing up in the first place.

You're attempting to solve a problem in the wrong methods.

Find out what you can about that error message box and do what you can to prevent that happening.  Don't expect to have much you can do when the PC is locked.

Comment: (Well the messagebox is not possible to stop, its a third party application, and why have tried all that, but yes i think it has to be unlocked) thanks.